# How to update this.router.url property based on some condition in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular-activatedroute

I am working on angular application where I want to update router url on some condition. below is the sample code:-

```
console.log(this.router.url) // it prints '/users'
this.location.replaceState('/users/1') // it updates the url bar with new url
console.log(this.router.url)  //it prints same again '/user'
```

is there any way i can change the current route url without refreshing or reloading the page.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to navigate without refreshing the page?
Try: `this.router.navigate(['/user/1']);` and check out the official [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Answer (score 0):

you should add a condition in the ngOnInit
if (this.router.url === '/cms/page/edit') {
this.page1= true

and then
add a *ngIf="page1" or *ngIf="!page1" to the html balise.

this worked for me ;).

Answer (score -1):

you probably should navigate to new route

```js
if (condition) {
  this.router.navigate('/users/1');
}
```

In Angular (as SPA) it won't refresh or reload page but instantiate component for new route. If you want display user information in only one `div` in the page without refreshing the rest (i.e. list of users), you can make use of `router-outlet`.

You can learn more [here](https://angular.io/guide/router)